# Is it possible to build Minecarts (rails) on Vanilla?

Tags: medieval-engineers

I'd like to have Minecarts on Rails to help me carry all the stones I get from mining.

Is it possible to build this infrastructure on Vanilla?

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using 2 Wheels per Catch Block:

[image]

Just don't look like a Minecart due to the size of its Wheels and of the rails (Round Timbers)... Real Minecarts would be welcome here.