# Is it possible to build Minecart Rail Curves on Vanilla?

Tags: medieval-engineers

Since there are no Minecarts not Rails on Vanilla, [I managed to build makeshift ones](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/399040/291368), but, beside the humongous scale, the rails can only be placed on a straight line, or at 90º degress, which hinders me from making curves. A railway with no curves is pretty useless outside Minecraft.

So, is it possible to curved Minecart Rails on Vanilla? How?